# Duda sobre InputStream en Java

Tags: java, socket

La duda es muy simple, al recoger los datos que un cliente me envía, los recojo con un buffer de 1024 bytes, si los datos que el cliente me envía es un simple "hola", en el String resultante tendré un hola seguido de caracteres NULL o algo así, no se muy bien que son porque tampoco se ve bien que sean NULL, con las imágenes se entenderá mejor:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  InputStream in = mSocket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = mSocket.getOutputStream();
            byte[] bufferRequest = new byte[1024];
            int bytesLeidos = in.read(bufferRequest, 0, 1024);
            String bufferReqStr = new String(bufferRequest);
            String[] argumentos = bufferReqStr.split("\n");
```

Cómo podría hacer para sacar solamente GET y por otro lado solo hola a secas, he probado con regex pero no se si es que no se puede o no se.

Gracias.

Comment: Código como texto, por favor. Lo otro, el buffer es de 1024, está inicializado el array, tienes unas posiciones con H O L A y el resto sin valor definido. Si el cliente no envía el terminador que esperas `\n`, vas a procesar los 1024 bytes.

Comment: Voy a editarlo para poner código como texto y gracias, ya lo he resuelto, voy a intentar hacerlo como expones. 
Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Vale, acabo de ver la respuesta, tengo que modificar

```
String bufferReqStr = new String(bufferRequest);
```

y añadir esto:

```
   String bufferReqStr = new String(bufferRequest, 0, bytesLeidos);
```

y con eso ya se leen los datos que me interesan.